# Will I be able to read from specific partitions from a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka framework to implement a kafka listener. Currently I'm reading from a topic. But, as per a certain requirement, I was asked for  a way to implement listener that will be reading from certain partitions from a kafka topic.

Is this a good practice to have different applications read from different partitions. Can you please help with the knowledge of how can I implement this through spring-kafka and java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContainerProperties` used for configuring a `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` has this ctor:

```
public ContainerProperties(TopicPartitionInitialOffset... topicPartitions) {
```

Where it is about:

```
**
 * A configuration container to represent a topic name, partition number and, optionally,
 * an initial offset for it. The initial offset can be:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@code null} - do nothing;</li>
 * <li>positive (including {@code 0}) - seek to EITHER the absolute offset within the
 * partition or an offset relative to the current position for this consumer, depending
 * on {@link #isRelativeToCurrent()}.
 * </li>
 * <li>negative - seek to EITHER the offset relative to the current last offset within
 * the partition: {@code consumer.seekToEnd() + initialOffset} OR the relative to the
 * current offset for this consumer (if any), depending on
 * {@link #isRelativeToCurrent()}.</li>
 * </ul>
 * Offsets are applied when the container is {@code start()}ed.
 *
 * @author Artem Bilan
 * @author Gary Russell
 */
public class TopicPartitionInitialOffset {
```

So, this way you can specify which partition from which topic and what offset to start to consume.

When we use partition-based configuration we end up with this function on the `KafkaConsumer`:

```
/**
 * Manually assign a list of partitions to this consumer. This interface does not allow for incremental assignment
 * and will replace the previous assignment (if there is one).
 * <p>
 * If the given list of topic partitions is empty, it is treated the same as {@link #unsubscribe()}.
 * <p>
 * Manual topic assignment through this method does not use the consumer's group management
 * functionality. As such, there will be no rebalance operation triggered when group membership or cluster and topic
 * metadata change. Note that it is not possible to use both manual partition assignment with {@link #assign(Collection)}
 * and group assignment with {@link #subscribe(Collection, ConsumerRebalanceListener)}.
 * <p>
 * If auto-commit is enabled, an async commit (based on the old assignment) will be triggered before the new
 * assignment replaces the old one.
 *
 * @param partitions The list of partitions to assign this consumer
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If partitions is null or contains null or empty topics
 * @throws IllegalStateException If {@code subscribe()} is called previously with topics or pattern
 *                               (without a subsequent call to {@link #unsubscribe()})
 */
@Override
public void assign(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
```

So, this is really standard practice to consume directly from particular partitions.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan. Also In order to post messages to a particular partition, Can you suggest how can it be done using spring-kafka.

Comment: There is a `KafkaTemplate` with its `send(String topic, Integer partition, K key, V data)`